# Redirect to homepage if attmpting to leave intranet

Tags: javascript, redirect, htaccess

I have a client who wants a WordPress-based intranet, but does not want it to be a launching point for web browsing. I'm guessing there is a way to do this with javascript or with htaccess.

I get that simply opening a new window will probably work around whatever solution is applied to the site.

I also get that this is not strictly a WordPress question, but in the case of an htaccess solution, it may be.

Comment: A "new window" or simply typing a new web address (or search query) in the browsers address bar? How do you imagine JavaScript or htaccess will help with this? If the user is trying to access the internet then they are already bypassing your "intranet". This is a network/infrastructure question.

Comment: Yes, I understand nothing will rule out opening a new window. However, is there no alert that can be triggered when entering a new url in the address bar and hitting enter?

Comment: You can issue a JavaScript modal alert (in the `window.beforeunload` event) if the user tries to navigate away from the site, however, the user is always in control (as they should be) - they simply click "Leave". Not sure what the intention is here? In what way do they "leave the intranet"? Do users on this network have access to the www? Are the user accounts or the browser "locked down" in any way?

Comment: if your client does not want users to access the net he should not provide net access at the network level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the solution or not but the .HTACCESS might be useful. You can ensure only IP: xxx.xx.xx can view the site and then deny others.

IF this is helpful, place this in your htaccess file. You will of course want to update the ip address below to the access granted to said wordpress site.

```
    Allow from 111.11.11.1
    Deny from all
```